# Updating selectors after delegate addition failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaError Domain Code=4099

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui

Is anyone able to explain this error, and what might have caused it? I've been trying to create a messaging app using Firebase's Realtime Database in SwiftUI, but am unable to read from the database and have been getting this error.

> Updating selectors after delegate addition failed with: Error
> Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named
> com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at
> lookup with error 3 - No such process."

I'm able to write to the database just fine but it doesn't seem to want to be read from, so I'm assuming it's because of whatever this error is. Thanks